# Is N-methylimidazole an unusual solvent, or are there more common substitutes for it?

Tags: applied-chemistry

I want to test a process that was documented in the literature using N-methylimidazole.

I am not doing academic research, but rather testing a documented reaction for application to an industrial process, so I don't believe I need lab-grade chemicals.

When I look for this solvent online I can only find lab suppliers (e.g., Matrix Scientific, Acros Organics, Alfa Aeser) selling tiny quantities at very high prices.

Is there something unique to this chemical as a "donor solvent" that is not reproduced by any more common or inexpensive solvent?  I have seen it mentioned frequently in organic chemistry papers, but since I can't find industrial suppliers I assume it's peculiar to research.

The application I'm interested in is chemical stripping of lead using [Rauchfuss's Elixir](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00061a035?journalCode=jacsat), which consists of sulfur as an oxidant and a donor solvent.  I haven't been able to learn why they used methylimidazole as the solvent in the study.  Obviously I would prefer one more widely and/or cheaply available.

Comment: What kind of price per unit are you looking for?

Comment: Something significantly less than $100/L.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_EN_CB1316726.htm 
http://www.lookchem.com/cas-616/616-47-7.html 
http://www.guidechem.com/cas-616/616-47-7.html  2000 RMB = $(USD)320 
 
http://ahjinao.en.alibaba.com/product/595605676-209523668/Time_honored_Supplier_of_N_Methylimidazole_CAS_No_616_47_7_.html 
http://www.alibaba.com/countrysearch/CN/n--methylimidazole-supplier.html 
http://www.buyersguidechem.com/chemical_supplier/N-Methylimidazole.php

Info and suppliers,  Note that a Chinese contract is often not the legal or philosophical equivalent of a Western contract.

Comment: That's funny!  But I feel like I'm missing something if I have to go overseas to get industrial quantities of a common organic compound.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Methylimidazole  http://www.basf.com/group/corporate/us/en/brand/1_METHYLIMIDAZOLE America is regulated, legislated, and benefitted out of business. War on Drugs, War on Terror, the coming War on 3-D Printing. Miraculous Plasti-Dip is CA-banned: "solvent-based."  Aluthane, a very real exposure hazard with lower solids content, is OK - "solvent-based *metallic* paint."

Answer (score 2):

From what I see in the paper they likely wanted a basic solvet, and pyridine may have had a high enough dipole moment.  For quantities this small you are going to pay a bit more than you would in bulk, though as far as organic reagents go the prices are fairly cheap.  Acros and Alfa-Aesar are both owned by Fisher-Thermo Scientific by the way. Try Sigma-Aldrich or TCI America if you haven't already.